# Appending a list on Firebase Realtime Database swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, append

I am using Firebase realtime database to store users lists of locations. At the moment instead of an item being added to the user list in firebase, its replaced. How do I get there to be an appended list which is created as a user adds locations into the tableview? So I would want the structure of the data to be:

USER_ID
     PlaceName: locationA
                locationB
                locationC

Is that possible to do? here is my code so far:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)
    for place in storedPlaces {
        storedNames.append(place.name)
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = storedNames[indexPath.row]

    let Pname: String = (cell.textLabel?.text!)!
    print(Pname)
     let PplaceID = "Hello"
    let post : [String: AnyObject] = ["storedName" : Pname as AnyObject, "placeID" : PplaceID as AnyObject]

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("PlaceNames").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(post)



    return cell
```

Comment: You need to [call `childByAuthId()` to add an item to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) or [`updateChildValues()` to selectively update child properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to let firebase define the location node keys:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("PlaceNames").child((user?.uid)!)
locationRef = databaseRef.childByAutoId()
locationRef.setValue(post)
```

This will result in a Firebase structure:

```
PlaceName
  uid_0
    -YUisisokapoksa
       storedName: "some name"
       placeID: "some id"
    -YNisimaii990js
       storedName: "some name"
       placeID: "some id
```

There's some info on the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) about using childByAutoId - in the updating or deleting data section

Comment: Hey thanks for this! this wasn't quite what I wanted, but you pointed me in the right direction so now I've worked it out... I put the childByAutoId() after the child((user?.uid)!) all in the same line and with that I got the uid under PlaceNames with the autoID's underneath that followed by the individual places. (so a new autoID is made for each entry into the table view) which was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great! It sounds like the structure I posted matches your description! If the answer helped, please accept it so it will help others as well.